# Keeping the pressed state of ActionBar Icons in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

### States of actionBar

---

**pressed state**::

[image]

**Default state**::

[image]

---

**What i am doing** ::

- I am using the splitted actionbar
- On click of icon in bottom, I am changing the fragment
- Functionality is working fine

---

**What i want**::

- Is it possible to keep the pressed state of the actionbar item  until
  i click the next actionbar icon
- Then when i say click the star in figure, i want to keep the star in
  pressed state as blue color and search icon to return to normal state

---

**Code that i use**::

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

         if(item.getItemId()==R.id.searchID){
            //SEARCH Button Handling
            //((View) item).setBackgroundResource(R.color.actionBarIconPressed);
            //item.setIcon(R.color.actionBarIconPressed);
            item.setEnabled(true);
            ft1=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft1.hide(fragment1);
            //Condition to check whether the fragment is already in container & based on that do appropriate actions
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("SearchFragmentTag")==null){             
                ft1.add(R.id.content_frame, fragSearch, "SearchFragmentTag");
                ft1.addToBackStack(null);
                ft1.commit();
            }else{
                ft1.remove(fragSearch);
                ft1.add(R.id.content_frame, fragSearch, "SearchFragmentTag");
                ft1.commit();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }    



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_sort_menu, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

---

**My Questions**::

1. How to modify my code to achieve this feature ?
2. Is it possible ?
3. What are the possible ways ?

Comment: Maybe by changing the selected background in *onOptionsItemSelected* by retrieving the view pressed and do a loop to reinit the others, (I am not sure that's the best way to do it but,) it might do the trick.

Comment: That is not possible by default, but you can use a custom view to achieve this.

Comment: @XaverKapeller & Fllo ... How about onCreateoptions menu and using a global state variable .... can that be done(Im just making a guess)

Comment: My first instinct too was changing the background like @Fllo suggested, but that is not possible for an item in the actionbar -  at least as far as I know. I think the only option really is a custom view.

Comment: Yes, you can @XaverKapeller. Because the items use `actionItemBackground` for the styles, it seems that it uses a layout container. Then you can change the background dynamically by cast the menu item in a View. Just tried, just tested, just worked ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onOptionsItemSelected`, you can cast the `MenuItem` into a `View` and then, change its background. I got a start answer however I think you can improve it and change it according to your needs:

**Init your ids in an array:**

```
int[] listItemId = { R.id.searchID, R.id.ratindID, R.id.likeID, R.id.shareID };
```

**Call your options item selected method:**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.searchID:
             // call private method with int 1
             onItemChangeBackground(1);
             ... // do some stuff
             return true;
         case R.id.ratindID:
             onItemChangeBackground(2);
             ... // do some stuff
             return true;
         case R.id.likeID:
             onItemChangeBackground(3);
             ...
             return true;
         case R.id.shareID:
             onItemChangeBackground(4);
             ...
             return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Change the background item by switching an int value:**

```
private void onItemChangeBackground(int i) {
    // Loop to reinit the background items
    for(int ii = 0; ii < listItemId.length; ii++) { 
        // Cast the MenuItem into a View
        ( (View) findViewById(listItemId[ii]) )
                 // And set the default background (for example dark)
                 .setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark));
    }
    // Selected background
    switch(i) {
        case 1: ( (View) findViewById(R.id.searchID) )
                 .setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
            break;
        case 2: ( (View) findViewById(R.id.ratindID) )
                 .setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
            break;
        case 3: ( (View) findViewById(R.id.likeID) )
                 .setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
            break;
        case 4: ( (View) findViewById(R.id.shareID) )
                 .setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
            break;
    }
}
```

You can also set a drawable with a selector by using `setBackgroundDrawable()` when you want to reinitialize the background items (as you do in the styles.xml). Tested, it works!

Another solution might be to use `invalidateOptionsMenu()`. This will clear and redraw the menu by recalling `onCreateOptionsMenu()` again. Keep in mind without call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` the last method will never be recalled, it's only called at the first rime of the activity's creation. That's why we need to invalidate its content:

**Update an integer for each item selected:**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.searchID){
        nbItemSelected = 1;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        ...
    } else if(...) {
        nbItemSelected = 2;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    } ...
}
```

**Then, change the background while you create the options:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_layout, menu);
    if(nItemSelected != 0) {
         // Find item, cast the selected item to a view
         ( (View) menu.findItem(listItemId[nItemSelected]) )
              // Change its background
              .setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
    } 
    ...
    return true;
}
```

I guess it is possible in this way too, it might work.

Comment: @Fllo .... That's Magic in the code .... True you are a Wizard ... Thanks for such a Detailed and clear explanation ...Works like a charm :) [+1] too :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating a TabBarView like for example those you can find in iOs?

If so, an split actionbar is not the best component, it is better to use a ViewPagerIndicator with a ViewPager component. In there you can create your custom icons with your custom icons states and backgrounds.

I have an spare snippet of code I created long time ago for an application that required that component. Maybe you can look it around and take what you need (but I advice you that the code is not the best you can find as I was in a hurry, things can be done better, much better):

https://gist.github.com/aldoborrero/70fbeb062fab0ccc7d87

Answer (score 0):

@Casper did you tried setting custom selector for your ActionBar? 
Refer one below

```
drawable/tab_bg_selector.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <!-- Active tab -->
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_customtabs" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
        <!-- Inactive tab -->
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/ab_transparent_customtabs" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
        <!-- Pressed tab -->
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_customtabs" android:state_pressed="true"/>
        <!-- Selected tab -->
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_customtabs" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
    </selector>
```

Comment: Also check this link for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074528/how-to-override-pressed-state-color-in-sherlock-action-bar